# The cause of this error is needed mounted but i cannot call mounted in here

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

> This the method i log out and clear all my user data

```
 static Future<void> logOutUser(BuildContext context) async {
    printMe("=============> Logout user all");
    AppConstant.clearData();
    await LocalStorage.deleteAllUserData();
    Provider.of<UserProvider>(context, listen: false).setLoginStatus(false);
    Navigator.push(
        context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginPage()));
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IDE is showing a lint advice, which is not a build time error; nonetheless, this lint is telling you there's a good chance that your code will throw a runtime error.

Why? Well, I guess [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzWaMpD1LHY&ab_channel=Flutter) does a pretty good job answering it.

As the video suggests, there are many ways to work around that.If you've understood the problem explained in the video, read [this usefeul Tweet](https://twitter.com/remi_rousselet/status/1554506008898199553) from the creator of Provider (and Riverpod) himself to have more intel onto this lint.

Finally, a straight answer to fix your code depends on your use case, as Remi said in the tweet. Provide more context (e.g. where is this function located at) and clearly type your question if you want a clear answer.